# Tensor product of coherent sheaves on projective n-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, coherent-sheaves

I am thinking about the functor $-\otimes \mathcal F$, where $\mathcal F$ is a coherent $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}$ module. The setting I am working in is the Grothendieck group of $\mathbb P^n$ and I want to define a product on it via some Tor terms. In any case, I need the functor above to go from coherent $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}$ modules to coherent $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}$ modules. Do I know this in general?

I know this in the affine case but I am sure it does not work for an arbitrary scheme $X$. But do I know this for $\mathbb P^n$?

Sincerely, slin0

Comment: Without smoothness, this will fail for arbitrary schemes, since if it did, the Grothendieck group would be a ring, not just a group. For the smooth case, alternating sum of the tors would give you a good definition, since this is a finite sum.

Comment: So in the smooth case, the tors (and so also the tensor product) go from coherent sheaves to coherent sheaves?

Comment: For smooth (any quasi-projective, smoothness is not necessary)  varieties, $Tor_i(A,B)$ for coherent sheaves $A,B$ are coherent.

Comment: Could you point out a reference for me or a hint where I can find this?

Comment: For coherence of tors, look up any commutative algebra book. Vanishing of higher tors for smooth varieties can also be found in any such book.

Answer (score 2):

The stacks project is really vast. For some reason I couldn't find this yesterday but for anyone looking for a reference for my question, [Tag 0AZR] in the stacks project
 deals with all of this.